# How to enumerate permutations in maple without the inbuilt function

Tags: maple

I want to write maple code without using the permute function maple such that I that can get each permutation at a time and as I do not want to store all the permutations in a list as it would require too much memory space when n is larger.

So I would like to say I have to permute [1,2,3] first I get 1,2,3 leave it , next get 2,1,3 leave it, 3,2,1 leave it and so I don't store them after using it.

The same way for combinations too without using the combinat to store entire in a list i want say choose from 1,2,3,4 say 3 elements at a time
I choose 1,2,3 leave it. Next I choose say 1,2,4 leave it without storing after I have just used it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the [combinat:-nextperm](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=combinat/nextperm&term=nextperm) command or the [Iterator:-Permute](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Iterator%2FPermute) command (more recent versions of Maple) to iterate over permutations individually.

In other words, these allow you to construct (and inspect/manipulate) the iterations individually without the full set being stored at any one time which is prohibitively expensive in memory. In fact, *this is the primary purpose of these commands*, to avoid storing the full set at once.

Similarly there are commands such as [combinat:-nextcomb](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=combinat/nextcomb&term=nextcomb), etc, for combinations.